# c++ how to output ply file in binary format

Tags: c++, ply-file-format

I am trying to create a binary PLY file, with the following header:

```
ply
format binary_little_endian 1.0
element vertex 43000
property float x
property float y
property float z
property float nx
property float ny
property float nz
property uchar red
property uchar green
property uchar blue
end_header
```

I have the following overloaded functions to write as binary (validated with another example):

```
inline void write_fbin(std::ofstream &out, float val) {
    out.write(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&val), sizeof(float));
}



inline void write_fbin(std::ofstream &out, unsigned char val) {
    out.write(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&val), sizeof(unsigned char));
}
```

I write the vertices info as follows:

```
write_fbin(ofstr, static_cast<float>(point.x));
write_fbin(ofstr, static_cast<float>(point.y));
write_fbin(ofstr, static_cast<float>(point.z));
write_fbin(ofstr, static_cast<float>(point.n_x));
write_fbin(ofstr, static_cast<float>(point.n_y));
write_fbin(ofstr, static_cast<float>(point.n_z));
write_fbin(ofstr, static_cast<unsigned char>(point.r));
write_fbin(ofstr, static_cast<unsigned char>(point.g));
write_fbin(ofstr, static_cast<unsigned char>(point.b));
```

where `point` is a struct of type

```
struct DensePoint {
    float x, y, z;
    float n_x, n_y, n_z;
    unsigned char r, g, b;
};
```

This does not work and produces an invalid ply file. However, if I use the same code (changing the header) to produce an ASCII version,

```
ofstr
            << point.x << ' '
            << point.y << ' '
            << point.z << ' '
            << point.n_x << ' '
            << point.n_y << ' '
            << point.n_z << ' '
            << static_cast<int>(point.r) << ' '
            << static_cast<int>(point.g) << ' '
            << static_cast<int>(point.b) <<
            '\n';
```

this works perfectly. What could be wrong?

Maybe I need to introduce a newline at the end of each vertex in the binary format?

Comment: Do you have an end of line after `end_header` ?

Comment: yes, both in binary and ascii

Comment: According to http://www.cs.virginia.edu/~gfx/Courses/2001/Advanced.spring.01/plylib/Ply.txt does your data have the correct number of bytes ? You could use fixed length type as uint8, etc ... to be sure

Comment: Please post an example output file, or at least some snippet of it.

Comment: @dkg my `write_fbin()` function guarantees that the size is correctly calculated

Comment: @RSahu that would make no sense I guess, as the file consists only of the header I indicated and some unreadable chars

Comment: Is the file opened in BINARY MODE ? If not, writing binary pattern will be subjected to the same OS character translation rule (if any) of text, so the binary form may not be as expected.

Comment: @EmilioGaravaglia yes

Comment: @EmilioGaravaglia that solved it! I was resetting the flags after I open! Do you want to post an answer for me to close the question?

Comment: I found a cpp header that is simple to integrate and can save/read PLY in binary/ascii formats, maybe can help others too: https://github.com/nmwsharp/happly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When writing / reading binary data to / from a file that seem don't match the expected format, chances are that there is a character translation in place at OS level that replaces certain bytes combinations with other (es 0x0C becoming 0x0C 0x0A).

You have most likely opened the file in text mode (the default for C++ stream) when it should have been binary, to let the OS behavior neutral.